# Adding custom directive on click of button in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

```
var testModule = angular.module("testModule",[]);
testModule.directive('addVehicle',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, instanceElement, attributes) {
            instanceElement.on('click',function() {
                angular.element(document.getElementById('vehicles')).append('<vehicle-table></vehicle-table>');
            });
        }
    }
});
testModule.directive('vehicleTable',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<table class="vehicleTable">' +
                '<tr><td class="vehicleData"><select></select></td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td class="vehicleData"><input type="text"></td></tr> ' +
                '<tr><td class="vehicleDataEnd"><input type="text"></td></tr>' +
                '</table>'
    }
});
```

Above is my angular JS fragment.when I click addVehicle(this is attribute of button element) I get the vehicleTable only as a tag but not as its template getting inserted in the DOM. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because directive need to be compiled and processed properly before they get rendered with thier template and behaviors here you are only appending an element.

use compile service  **$compile**

```
 var el = $compile( '<vehicle-table></vehicle-table>' )( scope );
 angular.element(document.getElementById('vehicles').append( el );
```

complete code for directive will be

```
testModule.directive('addVehicle',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, instanceElement, attributes) {
            instanceElement.on('click',function() {
                var el = $compile( '<vehicle-table></vehicle-table>' )( scope );
     angular.element(document.getElementById('vehicles').append( el );

            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? Thanks

Comment: Done:) It was helpful

Comment: Can I use $compile without passing in scope in case if I don't need scope as of now

Comment: you can give it a shot if it works and you dont need scope:) @user3519763

Comment: But it doesn't work.It throws error as Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: $compile( '<vehicle-table></vehicle-table>' ); with this?

Comment: @user3519763 if it doesnt work you can better pass scope. thats not a problem

Comment: Yes.I guess in the backend the Node for append function is not taking the actual markup

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you'd need to $compile the added directive:

```
link: function(scope, instanceElement, attributes) {
  instanceElement.on('click', function() {
    var newElem = $compile(angular.element("<vehicle-table>"))(scope)
    instanceElement.append(newElem);
  });
}
```

But just because you're writing a directive, doesn't mean that you should abandon normal Angular patterns. You could just do:

```
testModule.directive('addVehicle', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    template: "<vehicleTable ng-repeat='v in vehicles'></vehicleTable>",
    link: function(scope, instanceElement, attributes) {
      scope.vehicles = [];
      instanceElement.on('click', function() {
        scope.vehicles.push({}); // or whatever the object you need
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can I use $compile without passing in scope in case if I don't need scope as of now ?

Comment: You can compile without scope - this returns a link function. But to invoke the link function requires scope